# Multiple SSL/TLS certificates for different enpoints in GRPC

Tags: security, go, ssl, ssl-certificate, grpc

I want to be able to have clients require different certificates to be able to access different endpoints/services of our server. For example, a client trying register to hit the register endpoint will require a certificate issued by the root CA. Upon registration, the server will generate another certificate for the client to be able to access the rest of the application.

So the flow that I am trying to use is:

1. Server and client both generate certs from the root CA
2. Client tries to register with his/her initial cert
3. If registration is valid, then the server will generate a cert signed by the servers own cert. This new cert will have the credentials of the client (ip address, name , etc...)
4. Server returns the new cert to the client and the client can now access other endpoints/services

Is this a valid flow that I am trying to follow and is this possible using GRPC in Go?

Comment: By "server's own cert", do you mean that the server will have its own CA? If you really want separate certificate requirements (different CA as opposed to different CN contents), you'll need to do separate GRPC services, not multiple endpoints on the same service. You should also explain why this approach as opposed to just a simple secret like an API key. If the server it generating the private key, this is the same.

Comment: By "server's own cert", I do mean its own CA, but generated from the root CA. I initially did not want to do simple API keys is because it is a public p2p network where owners of the server can just leak the API keys or be the db gets hacked. But now im thinking if those API keys are hashed, then its fine if the hashes of those keys are leaked.

Comment: @Marc, the tls.Config contains a CA pool, not just a single CA certificate, so multiple servers/services are not necessary.

Comment: @GorrilaBeanz, yes, API keys should be treated like passwords. There is no significant difference.

Comment: @peter: this works if the grpc TLS state validation hooks are run after the method is known (and they pass the method), otherwise you can't validate the certificate chain based on the method and reject unwanted roots. I honestly don't remember, it could go either way.

Comment: @Marc, if you have granular permissions you do checks in the method in any case. Here, by inspecting [tls.ConnectionState.VerifiedChains](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ConnectionState), accessible through the [peer](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/peer) and [credentials](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials#TLSInfo) packages.